# Write .vsdx file to Response stream using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, response, visio, visio2013

What I tried so far

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-visio";
Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
Response.End();
```

Here file is of FileInfo type, I am not sure how to write this .vsdx file to response Stream.

Comment: Are you aware that a `.vsdx` file is essentially a `.zip` file with a different extension? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj228622.aspx

Comment: Yes I know, I was thinking as we do for .vdx file we simply write .xml contents and specify Its Content type as Visio(as mention above), it prompts user to Open. and on Click it shows the Exact .vdx file which was written to response Stream.